# Count lines from Microsoft Word file regardless of automatic line wrapping

Tags: python, ms-word, text-processing, data-science, python-docx

I have a .docx Microsoft Word file formatted roughly as follows:

```
TAG    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
       elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
TAG_2  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
       elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
       et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
TAG    Text text text text text text text text text text
```

Where indentation is achieved by wrapping long lines automatically (if copy-pasted in a simple txt editor, the above text would result in 3 lines instead of 7).

My task is to automatically count the number of lines assigned to a tag, s.t. the above file would result in something like:

```
TAG    2
TAG_2  4
TAG    1
```

Right now I do it manually, by specifiying a font file, font size, and average line lenght, and dividing the lenght of a line (measured with `PIL.ImageFont.getsize()`) but this approach is really error-prone and does not cover all possible situations (like fonts changing mid-file).
Unfortunately I have no control over the file, so I cannot properly format it before counting lines (as reason would demand).

Is there a way to do this in Python? I've found the [python-docx package](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/) but is seems kinda limited in its capabilities.

Also note that the .docx format is not necessary mandatory, I could also convert the file to .odt if necessary.

Attaching a screenshot of my setup (in LibreOffice) to make it more clear.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can tackle the problem directly accessing the underlying structure of the .docx file, which is essentially xml. Unfortunately this maybe be not as easy as it may seem, depending mainly on the formatting of the document.

Comment: So initially, that document has one line per tag, right ? But you want to measure, on that particular .docx file, how this changes ?

Because as you mention, depending on the editor you use, that would change ("if copy-pasted in a simple txt editor, the above text would result in 3 lines instead of 7") ?

The return-to-line character is \n, couldn't you just count how many times that one appears ?

Do you have a consistent separator between TAG and the prose part ? Maybe tab or ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, author answered "The actual line count is always one per tag, but lines are rendered differently based on the font size, font face, and specific margin chosen for the document. There is no `\n` at the end of automatically wrapped lines."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the number of lines & words in all paragraphs in a Document with VBA:

```
Sub ParaStatsCount()
Dim Para As Paragraph
For Each Para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
  With Para.Range
    MsgBox .Text & vbCr & "Line Count = " & .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticLines) & vbCr _
      & "Word Count = " & .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

If you can automate Word with Python, the same (and other) methods should be available to it.

Comment: Marking this as solved even if it doesn't apply 100%, thanks